# How to remove the specific attribute from XmlDocument

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

My Xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order>
    <class>
      <about></about>
    </class>
    <dataset>
       <subjects>
          <subject>
            <addresses>
              <address/>
            </addresses>
           </subject>
        </subjects>            
    </dataset>        
 </order>
```

To reorder the xml element and to add namespace i did it as per below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order>
    <class>
      <about></about>
    </class>
    <dataset>
       <subjects>
          <subject>                
           </subject>
        </subjects>
        <addresses>
              <address/>
        </addresses>            
    </dataset>        
 </order>
```

I did using below code

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlClueReqToLexisNexis.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "http://example.com/abc");
XmlNode order = xmlClueReqToLexisNexis.SelectSingleNode("//ab:order", nsmgr);
XmlNode dataset = xmlClueReqToLexisNexis.SelectSingleNode("//ab:order//ab:dataset", nsmgr);
var subjects = order.SelectSingleNode("//ab:order//ab:dataset//ab:subjects", nsmgr);
```

I am able to reorder and add namespace to it but it left behind xmlns attribute 
as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order>
    <class>
      <about></about>
    </class>
    <dataset>
       <subjects>
          <subject xmlns="">                
           </subject>
        </subjects>
        <addresses xmlns="">
              <address/>
        </addresses>            
    </dataset>        
 </order>
```

I want to remove only attribute xmlns="" out of addresses and subject

Please suggest me the best way to do that.

Comment: Are you actually using LINQ to XML or not? Your title talks about `XmlDocument`, whereas LINQ to XML would be `XDocument`. Are you creating this document in code, or reading it and then manipulating it? More context please.

Comment: Yes i am creating this doc in code.        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr= new XmlNamespaceManager(myXml.NameTable);
>       nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab","http://example.com/abc");
>       XmlNode order= myXml.SelectSingleNode("//ab:order", nsmgr);
>       XmlNode dataset= myXml.SelectSingleNode("//ab:order//ab:dataset",nsmgr);

Comment: i created it using XDocument . converted it XmlDocument to reorder the elements.

Comment: Please put the code you're using *in the question* rather than just in comments... ideally, show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. You just need to create the elements in the right namespace, but it's hard to show that without seeing your code. It's not clear to me why you're using `XmlDocument` at all, to be honest... LINQ to XML is generally a much cleaner API.

Comment: Please refer the code above... help me here

Comment: Why do you keep quoting code? I fixed the first version of your question, and now you've requoted it. You still haven't explained why you're using `XmlDocument` at all, nor have you shown the code that creates the document to start with.